# How to compare a global variable to a string in Clips?

Tags: clips

In my system the user inputs a Y or N to answer simple questions. I call this rule after every question to increment a counter. There are some general problems with my code but i can't see where

```
(defrule QPain
         (initial-fact)
         =>
         (printout t "Are You In Pain? " crlf) 
         (bind ?*Answer* (read)) 
)
(defrule IncSym
     (test(=(str-compare (?*Answer*) "y")0))
      =>
     (bind ?*symcount* (+ ?*symcount* 1))
)
```

Thanks

Comment: It is not necessary to add the initial-fact to a rule with no other conditions; it is added automatically in versions of CLIPS prior to version 6.3. The initial-fact functionality was deprecated in the 6.3 release; it is still asserted by a reset, but rules without conditions no longer rely on it. In the 6.4 release, the initial-fact is no longer asserted, so rules that explicitly match this fact will no longer be activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntactic errors can be corrected as follows:

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> (defglobal ?*Answer* = nil)
CLIPS> (defglobal ?*symcount* = 0)
CLIPS> 
(defrule QPain
   =>
   (printout t "Are you in pain? ") 
   (bind ?*Answer* (read)))
CLIPS>    
(defrule IncSym
   (test (eq ?*Answer* y))
   =>
   (bind ?*symcount* (+ ?*symcount* 1))) 
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Are you in pain? y
CLIPS> (show-defglobals)
?*Answer* = y
?*symcount* = 0
CLIPS>
```

This won't produce the behavior you're expecting, however, since ?*symcount* will not be incremented. The behavior of global variables and why you should not be using them in the manner you're attempting has been discussed previously:

[How exactly (refresh) works in the clips?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698181/how-exactly-refresh-works-in-the-clips)
[CLIPS: forcing a rule to re-evaluate the value of a global variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30017688/clips-forcing-a-rule-to-re-evaluate-the-value-of-a-global-variable)
[Number equality test fails in CLIPS pattern matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842144/number-equality-test-fails-in-clips-pattern-matching)
[CLIPS constant compiler directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118807/clips-constant-compiler-directive)
[How can I run the clips with out reset the fact when using CLIPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23684362/how-can-i-run-the-clips-with-out-reset-the-fact-when-using-clips)

Instead of using global variables to track responses and symptoms, you should use facts or instances. Here's one approach:

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate symptom
   (slot id)
   (slot response))
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate symptom-list
   (multislot values))
CLIPS> 
(deffacts initial
   (symptom-list))
CLIPS>    
(defrule QPain
   =>
   (printout t "Are you in pain? ")
   (assert (symptom (id in-pain) (response (read)))))
CLIPS>   
(defrule IncSym
   (symptom (id ?id) (response y))
   ?f <- (symptom-list (values $?list))
   (test (not (member$ ?id ?list)))
   =>
   (modify ?f (values ?list ?id)))
CLIPS>    
(defrule symptoms-found
   (declare (salience -10))
   (symptom-list (values $?list))
   =>
   (printout t "Symptom count: " (length$ ?list) crlf))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Are you in pain? y
Symptom count: 1
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Are you in pain? n
Symptom count: 0
CLIPS>
```

And another:

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate symptom
   (slot id)
   (slot response))
CLIPS>    
(defrule QPain
   =>
   (printout t "Are you in pain? ")
   (assert (symptom (id in-pain) (response (read)))))
CLIPS>   
(defrule symptoms-found
   (declare (salience -10))
   =>
   (bind ?count (find-all-facts ((?f symptom)) (eq ?f:response y)))
   (printout t "Symptom count: " (length$ ?count) crlf))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Are you in pain? y
Symptom count: 1
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Are you in pain? n
Symptom count: 0
CLIPS>
```